ASP.NET Core - yarp proxy not forward request to correct instance of an API
I am learning about yarp proxy in ASP.NET Core. I have configured as below. But it always points to yarp.api1 and never to yarp.api2. Now I am using round robin policy. I also try with random but it is the same result. Does anyone know what this problem is? Thank you.
appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ReverseProxy": { //config for proxy and LB
    "Routes": {
      "route1": {
        "ClusterId": "cluster1",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "{**catch-all}"
        }
      }
    },
    "Clusters": {
      "cluster1": { //Load balancing
        "LoadBalancingPolicy": "RoundRobin",
        "Destinations": {
          "destination1": {
              "Address": "http://yarp.api1:8080",
            "destination2": {
              "Address": "http://yarp.api2:8080"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Docker compose:
services:
  yarp.api1:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}yarp.api1
    container_name: yarp.api1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Yarp.WebApi/Dockerfile
    cpus: 1
    mem_limit: "0.5G"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    ports:
      - 7001:8080
    networks:
      - proxybackend

  yarp.api2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}yarp.api2
    container_name: yarp.api2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Yarp.WebApi/Dockerfile
    cpus: 1
    mem_limit: "0.5G"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    ports:
      - 7002:8080
    networks:
      - proxybackend

  yarp.apigateway:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}yarp.apigateway
    container_name: yarp.apigateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Yarp.APIGateway/Dockerfile
    cpus: 1
    mem_limit: "0.5G"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    ports:
      - 7000:8080
    networks:
      - proxybackend

networks:
  proxybackend:
    name: proxybackend
    driver: bridge

Controller:
namespace Yarp.WebApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController() : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("GetServerName")]
        public string GetServerName()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            return HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
        }
    }
}

It always redirects to yarp.api1:

Both API instances are working well:

Docker logs:

